# How to open a "Open directory" GUI with C++ in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, system-calls

I am writing a C++ program for pattern recognition in OpenCV. Prompting for a user input, when user enters the option for "Viewing the Image Database", I want a window showing the files in that directory. I tried a system call with

```
system("nautilus /home/sample/index.jpg");
```

but it says that it could not find the directory and asks to check spelling. I was wondering if it was because of executing the program from a different directory. Could anyone explain why this is happening? If so, how to go around it?

Comment: For GUI application features on Ubuntu, have a look at [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/).

Comment: Don't run your programs with `system`, use the proper system calls for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open nautilus, put the full path (probably */usr/bin/nautilus* but you can easily discover using the *which* command).

Some further notes:

- Not all Linux systems have Nautilus (Mint, for example, has replaced Nautilus with *nemo*)
- If you want to make interactive windows, then you need a proper graphics library. In this case, since you are programming in C++, I suggest you to use Qt which is available on all Linux desktop distributions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used the which command on nautilus and it returned usr/bin/nautilus. When I replace it in the program, it returns this : sh: 1: usr/bin/nautilus: not found.

How fast can I develop an "Open Directory" with Qt. I know it depends on my effort but since I am completely new to Javascript / Qt. Could you tell me about that too?

Comment: I got it..! :) Sorry I dint use a "/" before usr in usr/bin/nautilus and thats why I got that error. Thank you so much. I don't have to use Qt now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use default set file manager, not nautilus or any other. 
Try to look over here: [Linux default applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications), [How to find the default file manager](https://superuser.com/questions/465495/how-to-find-the-default-file-manager)

Comment: The link how to find the default manager was helpful in finding another way to do what I wanted. xdg-open worked. :) thanks.